# ajax post weird issue

Tags: ajax, post, request, response

I'm not so good with jQuery but I have checked my code against a syntax validator and everything is fine, it even works ("half") code is the following

```
$("#entrar").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      
      send = {"usuario": $("#userid").val()}
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/",
   datatype: "json",
   data: JSON.stringify(send),
   contentType: "application/json;",
   success: function (response) {
   const obj = JSON.parse(response);
   console.log("Si returnea");
   console.log(obj);
   setTimeout(function(es) {
               }, 10000);
     },
   });
 });
```

as you can see the request is fired up on button click, everything works until I want to log the response as it doesn't log anything however if I check my response tab on network tab on developer tools I get a JSON response which is

```
{"letras": "O***** S***** U*****"}
```

nevertheless it doesn't seem I can get it on console or even process the response could you please help me?

Comment: ok solved it by myself the whole problem was 

      send = {"usuario": $("#userid").val()} somehow i confused i was in still in python
forgot a simple var before send thanks anyway